# how to join three table in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have problem when joining my tables the error says Undefined variable: spps

```
        $siswas = DB::table('siswa')
        ->join('kelas', 'siswa.id_kelas', '=', 'kelas.id_kelas')
        ->join('spp', 'spp.id_spp', '=', 'siswa.id_spp' )
        ->get();  

        $kelass = DB::table('kelas')->get();
        return view('admin.data_siswa',compact('siswas','kelass'));

        $spps = DB::table('spp', 'kelas')->get();
        return view('admin.data_siswa',compact('siswas','spps'));

        

    }
```

i dont know how to defining the spp table, any one please suggest me idea

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in the joining , the problem is with two return statement!

the exception won't reach the last return, you should simply united them.

```
 $siswas = DB::table('siswa')
        ->join('kelas', 'siswa.id_kelas', '=', 'kelas.id_kelas')
        ->join('spp', 'spp.id_spp', '=', 'siswa.id_spp' )
        ->get();  

        $kelass = DB::table('kelas')->get();
        $spps = DB::table('spp', 'kelas')->get();
   return view('admin.data_siswa',compact('siswas','spps','kelass'));
```

Answer (score 0):

pass only one parameter  in DB::table($tableName);

```
$spps = DB::table('spp')->get();
```